# PC freezes in games and waking from sleep

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, bsod, gpu, sleep

**Problem**

I've had intermittent PC problems that I thought were solved, but Doom Eternal showed me otherwise yesterday since it happened again.

For a while earlier this year when playing some more GPU intensive games I would get either a black screen or frozen image and have to hard reset. No time for Windows to write any error logs. Occasionally it would be a BSOD (error message varied - nothing useful or consistent).

Playing with the case open, and reducing GPU power to 90%, seemed to help delay issues but not fully. So I thought it was a heat issue.

The problem is that it also has issues waking from sleep. Sometimes it would BSOD instantly. Other times like this morning, I would come down after my PC was meant to be asleep and see fans and lights on but no responsiveness, as though it had tried to wake and failed.

I have also tried my prior GPU (GTX 970) and replicated the behaviour, but I sometimes saw the same issues a couple of times on my last system too, along with what seemed to be memory corruption (programs would act weird and crash randomly as uptime increased, and more sleep/wake cycle would speed this up while a reboot would reset it). The only shared components are peripherals and HDD/SSD.

Since I don't have a shop of spare parts, how would you attempt to diagnose this? I thought it might be GPU heat issues but I got an error when swapping the GPU, plus both CPU and GPU temps are within range so that would mean inconsistent readings (bad thermal paste?). I ran memtest. If it's a part I'm leaning towards PSU or motherboard. But maybe it's a disk error?

Since I had problems on a prior build is it possible the power draw in the room itself has problems? Heavy gaming load and waking from sleep would both spike the power draw?

**Attempted fixes**

Swap GPU, run DDU to reset drivers, update drivers, run Memtest and CPU/GPU stressers (these don't seem to trigger it like games do), set GPU power to 90% (seemed to help the most), open case, wait for winter (also seemed to help - we're coming into summer now, but I've also been avoiding more strenuous games), change sleep mode to hibernate (slower, seems to help reduce error rate when waking but not fully), clean with canned air, disable sleep mode (avoids the wake from sleep issue but not convenient), disable virtualisation (the issues did only start a while after turning it on in the BIOS to run VMWare and it's still on right now, but I can't see a reason this would matter), unplug HDDs (didn't help, but can't unplug SSD).

**Specs**

**GPU** Gigabyte GeForce RTX2060 6G OC **CPU** Ryzen 2600 **RAM** 1x16GB (G Skill F4-3200C16D-16GFX FlareX) **Board** MSI B450M Gaming Plus **PSU** Antex Neo ECO Classic 650W 80+ Bronze (I did have someone tell me the PSU might be a little weak) **OS** Win10 **Disks** Samsung SSD hosting the OS + 2x SATA HDD

Comment: You should check your drive's SMART info to see if there are any obvious problems there. Your issue sounds like it could be a dying SSD or HDD. If you can make a bootable Linux USB stick you can stress test your system without using the SSD or HDD at all, which will rule out whether it is related to a failing drive or not.

Comment: @Romen interesting idea, do you have a suggested full-system stress test? I wasn't as easily able to trigger failures on Windows in stress tests, but games use the full system so it could be something like paging from disk. Once I can replicate it in Windows more easily that'll help assure me a non-failure on Linux indicates the SSD. Re: SMART, Samsung Magician says all good on the SSD and IIRC I did run for a time with HDDs connected and it crashed but maybe I should try again.

Comment: For reference I did run OCCT and it crashed once (black screens) but then not again on subsequent runs, and it's not available on Linux. Without a repeatable trigger it's proving tough to diagnose.